# How to log UUID of api request payload on every log messages with python?

Tags: python, logging, module, microservices

I'm working on a micro services where i need to log the uuid recieved on a payload to the cloud based logger. But i've one module calling another module, so for every submodule functions to log the messages with uuid, i need to pass uuid to every function i call, but that's a bad idea, is there a better way of doing this ??

Illustration of what i'm trying to achieve:

```py
def call_bar(uuid):
    app.logger.info("Something coming with uuid: {uuid}")   

def call_foo(uuid):
    # 
    app.logger.info("Something coming with uuid: {uuid}")    
    call_bar(uuid)

def flask_view():
    # i get a uuid here
    app.logger.info("Something coming with uuid: {uuid}")
    call_foo(uuid)
```

The issue in the above code is i need to explicitly pass the value to every function i call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logger component of [Lambda Power tools](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/latest/core/logger/) does this for us on AWS. the code setup is pretty minimal:

```
from aws_lambda_powertools import Logger

logger = Logger()

def flask_view():
    request_uuid = i_get_a_uuid_here()
    logger.append_keys(uuid=request_uuid)
    call_foo()

def call_foo()
    logger.info("foo happened")
```

This would get you a json log line than line that  as well as bunch of other fields has the following keys.

```
{
   "message": "foo happened", "uuid": "<request_uuid>" 
}
```

if your not on aws lambda, I'd take a look at [structlog](/https://www.structlog.org/)  its  `log.bind(uuid=uuid)` works similarly allowing you to add keys that get used for subsequent log entries.